# Entity Framework 4 ApplyCurrentValues does not update nonnullable decimal column to zero

Tags: frameworks, entity

When I try to update a decimal(19,4) nonnullable field to zero (0) with ApplyCurrentValues method, the field is not updated and keeps its old value. Any value except Zero is updated. And other decimal fields with nullable attribute could also be set to zero.

The code used is below:

```
public Int32 saveEntity(tblEntity entity)
    {
        using (conn)
        {
            Container _context = new Container();

            if (entity.ID != 0)
            {
                var stub = new tblEntity() { ID = entity.ID };
                _context.tblEntitySet.Attach(stub);
                _context.tblEntitySet.ApplyCurrentValues(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                _context.tblEntitySet.AddObject(entity);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return entity.ID;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the `ApplyCurrentValues` method can be used like you are using it.  As far as I understand, this method maps changes from a detached entity to an attached entity *with the same entity key* ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx)).

So you may not be able to `ApplyCurrentValues` when you do not have and `entity.ID`.  It seems that the `ApplyCurrentValues` would work better in your `else` statement.

I would suggest looking up the object out of the context using a query, applying the changes and then saving.

Comment: Entity always have a column named ID (primary key), Above code works as expected, however only a nonnullable decimal columns is not updated to zero.

Comment: Does non-nullable double or float create the same behavior?

Comment: I didn't try it for double or float types. By the way when I use

Instead of: 
var stub = new tblEntity() { ID = entity.ID };
_context.tblEntitySet.Attach(stub);

When I use :
_context.tblEntitySet.Attach(_context.tblEntitySet.Single(s => s.ID == entity.ID));

Everything works as expected. By the way I use EF4 in a WCF service that is consumed by .Net Framework 3.5 application. So we can say that it works as "disconnected" mode.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are loosing the `EntityKey`, which is the key that is tracked by the change manager.  This is not the same as the ID key field.  By, querying the entity from the context by ID, you are re-populating the `EntityKey`.